# Don’t fail Gradle build when test task fails

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit

I have a Gradle test task that I have ignoreFailures = true on, which allows everything to run after that, but still causes the build itself to fail.

Although it may seem weird, in my scenario, the failing test task is correct, so I would like to capture that fact and mark the build as successful, is there a way I can do this in a Gradle task?

There seems no way I can see of capturing the result and mutating it prior to the task using it as a build result

Hope that makes sense!

Cheers